# how to fetch the record from mongodb to part of html page automaticalyy without refreshing/reloading manually. using MEAN stack

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

Need some help reading Mean stack. I have a requirement like,

When a record is inserted into database, part of html page should get displayed with the new inserted record without reloading/refreshing manually.

Html page should get automatically updated with new record.

observations so far:
I am already using angularjs, nodejs and mongodb.
Using refresh() function, able to update part of hrml page manually.
I am to insert the record from html page to mongodb.

Comment: You should use socket.io to get instantly newly inserted records from mongodb. You should call that refresh function in socket.io

Answer (score 0):

You should use websockets ( [socket.io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io) is a good option ).

In the route responsible for document insertion/update on the backend, you should emit a `new_document` signal with the document's body to all sockets in the site...

Example:

```js
app.post('/api/posts', (req, res) => {
  Post.insert(postBody).then(body => {
    io.emit('new_document', body); // Broadcast to all websocket clients
    res.json(body);
  }).catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).json({error: err.message});
  });
});
```

Then, in the front-end, you should listen for the `new_document` event and call the `refresh()` function as callback or, even better, write a function to add just the new document.

Example:

```js
socket.on('new_document', function (body) {
    // ... code to add body to HTML ...
});
```

Comment: I am already using it, i want refresh() function to be called automatically without any submit button